# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I have an XML file and want to insert the data into a database with php.
A sample of XML file is:

```
<shops>
 <shop>
   <code>HM</code>
   <name>Beauty</name>
   <address>
     <address_name>George St </address_name>
     <city>New York</city>
   </address>
 </shop>
</shops>
```

I want to insert the values of code,name,address_name and city into my database with php.

My php code is:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("shops.xml");

$xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('shop');
$itemCount = $xmlObject->length;
for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
  $name = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $code = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('code')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $sql  = "INSERT INTO `shop` (name,code) VALUES ('$name', '$code')";
  mysql_query($sql);
} 

$xmlObject_n = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('address');
for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
  $address_n = $xmlObject_n->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('address_name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $city      = $xmlObject_n->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('city')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $sql_n     = "INSERT INTO `place` (address,city) VALUES ('$address_n', '$city')";
  mysql_query($sql_n);
}
```

While the data for the table shop in the first for loop are loaded properly, I get the following error for the second loop:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this in order to get the values for the element address?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the middle `"` in `$xmlDoc->load("shops".xml");` **Too many quotes** The code highlighting alone should have told you that

Comment: I don't see any tags `number` or `siteid`.

Comment: @MarcB Was that edit a good idea? Are you sure that was just a typo

Comment: @RiggsFolly: if that typo was in the original code, it would've been a fatal parse error, and you'd never get to the "non-object" error.

Comment: Sorry,typo error. Only the values of address element are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `<number>` tag in your XML, which means that this:

```
$name =$xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

will return an empty array, because there's no matching tags.

if a tag is optional, then you can NOT assume that it will be there, and your DOM code must take that into account:

```
$numbers = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('number');
if ($numbers->length > 0) {
   $number = $numbers->item(0);
}
```

Comment: It was a typo error.  Is there a way to get the address_name and city values?

Comment: yes, but you have to do exactly as I showed above, and check if your ->find() and ->get...() calls actually succeeded. otherwise your code will just keep blowing up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, I don't get this error but the data cannot be inserted into my table when I am running the sql query in my code.

Comment: then start debugging: all of your is assuming that nothing could ever go wrong, hence your original fatal-error. you don't check if the query calls succeeded. in other words, the universe could be melting down and your code would be happily watching the lego movie and singing "everything is awesome"